# Excel VBA - Merge across

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tricky situation. I have a column A with only headers and column B contains text. Now I would like to get the text from column B to start in column A. If there's text in column A, B will always be empty.

```
A            B
Title 1
             Text 1
             Text 2
Title 2
             Text 1
             Text 2
```

How could I get it so the text in column B is put in column A. Range is set until a complete empty row is found. (A1 to S1 no values in the cells = empty row)
I was thinking about merging cells, but that's perhaps not neat.

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? This uses merging and also takes into account where A and B are both filled up.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet5")

    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A" & i & ":" & "B" & i)) = 1 And _
            Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) = 0 Then
                With .Range("A" & i & ":" & "B" & i)
                    .Merge
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOW UP**

If you don't want merging and A will always remain empty when there is a value in B then we can move the value from Col B into Col A like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet5")

    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) = 0 Then
                .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
                .Range("B" & i).ClearContents
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So the lastrow is the first row in B that's completely empty? (A to S) And you seem to merge A & B, but if I wanted to cut/paste the value into A, how would that be?

Comment: No lastrow is the last row which is non empty in Col B. updating the code with your recent request.

Comment: You don't want "S" because you are planning to move value from "B" and not from "S". Let's say "S" is till row 100 and "B" is till Row 15 then no point looping till 100 as the cells from B16 to B100 will be empty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8025/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-tom)